# How create type from interface types

Tags: typescript

Can you please tell me how to create a type containing types from the specified interface?
Example:

```
interface SomeInterface {
   x:string
   y:number
}
```

expect to get something like

```
type SomeInterfaceTypes = string | number
```

Necessary for the method that sets the fields of an object

```
let obj = {x: 'tst', y: 0}

setObject( field: keyof SomeInterface: value: ??? ) {
   this.obj[field] = value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question you actually asked is to use `SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface]` (but keep reading):

```typescript
interface SomeInterface {
   x:string
   y:number
}

type SomeInterfaceTypes = SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface];
//   ^? - SomeInterfaceTypes = string | number
const a: SomeInterfaceTypes = "x";  // Works
const b: SomeInterfaceTypes = 42;   // Also works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhQB4BcAzmFKAObkUCe1IArpgEbSkAvqVJg2ABxQZseSLEQQAKhIi1kAXjRZc+eUgDaAawht0MLTN2EIAXQDcpAPSOKyAHoB+UgnQh6yOGoLHTlrZUk1TQAiSii7CmdkAHV0KENab19-XiDpEIIFcNUNZAAWACZ4hJcAQQAbWnRkAHdU9NIgA)

**But**, I wouldn't use that type for your function, it would mean `inst.setObject("x", 42)` would work, even though `x` has the type `string`, not `number`.

Instead, use a generic function/method:

```typescript
setObject<Key extends keyof SomeInterface>(field: Key, value: SomeInterface[Key]) {
    this.obj[field] = value;
}
```

That way, TypeScript can require that the key and value match up. The key's type is inferred from whatever you pass for the first argument, and then the value's type is inferred from the key's type. So this works:

```typescript
inst.setObject("x", "ok");
```

...but this fails, because the value has the wrong type:

```typescript
inst.setObject("x", 42);
//                  ^^−−− Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhQB4BcAzmFKAObkUCe1IArpgEbSkAvqVIIANnFq1kAUUpxMABzEoyFCul4Aramiy58sRCgC8JGsgDkYepYA0yDsgAMggNwj1yWhDAB5bQgEMAAeAGkINmQISkgQABNpAGtI9Bg9bDxIIyQAPgAKGGAIMXjdCLYHADc4MS4IXQxMw0IIAG0KgF0AShJWLwowAAtgWgA6TS02opL4zuQzGrqIfuRhYVF0EHpkUB2zEAgAd1l5JRV87o9SPbAxn39A4PyAIkoXhxf0JJerm+27g8AlogmBXu8HAAWABMfwA9HCBkjkQA9FGAJCJMcgAIJQJg8CDgZBpZBgNiKFCWbh8aCWXbSEDoMDISS0YBMEBwXgqUnoZCKOBQBS+aDE9JkilWeiMEBMSxjfLQgDMkIArN0gA)